# Мне надо задавать имена обьектов динамически формируя их. Java

Tags: java

Грубый пример:

```
String a = "Aaa";
Object a = new Object();
```

При этом мне надо чтобы oбьект получил имя 'Aaa'. На такую запись компилятор выдаёт ошибку, а как ещё записать я не знаю. Помогите плиз.

Comment: "Мне надо ..." - нет, Вам не надо. XY Problem - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @Igor лучше дать ссылку на [русскую версию](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/709/204271).

Comment: Я не знаю, возможно ли это вообще, но то, что у вас возникло такое желание -- это крайне удивительно. Я не могу представить, для чего бы это могло понадобиться. Наверняка для решения вашей задачи есть намного более простой и изящный способ. Может быть, вам можно использовать `Map` для хранения объектов и доступа к ним по неким строковым именам. Но не путайте эти строковые обозначения с именами переменных.

Comment: Может и есть, но я новичок и могу этого не знать. А вот для чего мне это надо : У меня есть метод добавления обьекта в ArrayList, при этом значения полей этого обьекта пользователь должен вводить с клавиатуры, что-то типа этого : Car ? = new Car(in.next(),in.next()); И вот как сделать так чтобы вместо знака вопроса появлялось какое-то имя, ведь если я задам имя обьекта например "о", а обьектов будет 100, то имена будут повторятся и будет error. - @m.vokhm

Comment: @Никита создали объект o, сложили его в список, и всё, o снова свободно для следующего объекта.

Comment: @tym32167 но в списке не может быть больше чем 1 объект "о"

Comment: @Никита да, но o уже к тем объектам отношения не имеет.

Comment: *в списке не может быть больше чем 1 объект "о"* конечно может. каждый вновь созданный объект `о` - это новый объект, который имеет свои уникальные значения полей. Если вам нужно хранить названия машин, то создаете в объекте `о` поле, напр. `name` и каждому вновь созданному объекту `о`, присваиваете свое имя `о.name = "bmv"` и тд. все эти объекты складываете в список

Comment: Все равно непонятна сверхзадача. Попробуйте так: (1) нажмите кнопку «править» под вопросом, чтобы добавить в него детали; (2) добавьте код, который приводит у Вас к ошибке; (3) расскажите что должен делать код не в плане программирования (объектов/переменных), а в плане результата: что код должен вывести, рассчитать и т.п.

Answer (score 0):

Создавать переменные с динамическими создаваемыми именами в `Java` вряд ли возможно, а если и возможно, то об этом мало кому известно, и это само по себе недвусмысленно говорит о том, что это и не нужно. Даже если каким-то чудом это можно сделать, то как нам потом использовать переменные, чьи имена не известны?

Вам по сути нужно другое. Если я правильно понял, вам нужно динамически (во время выполнения) создавать объекты с какими-то именами (т. е. строковыми обозначениями, не путать с именами переменных в `Java`), чтобы впоследствии можно было как-то работать с этими объектами -- вывести список этих обозначений, находить объект по его имени и т. п.

Есть простые способы решить эту задачу. Если нужно просто связать какое-то имя с каким-то набором значений, то можно описать класс, содержащий имя и нужные значения, и создавать объекты этого класса. Имена таких объектов будут содержаться в них самих. Если же впоследствии нужно получать к таким объектам быстрый доступ по имени, а сам объект не обязан "знать" свое имя, то можно использовать словари (`Map`, иногда называют "карта" или "отображение"). Это набор пар <ключ, значение>, который позволяет быстро найти значение по его ключу. Вы можете использовать имя в качестве ключа, а объект, который связан с этим именем -- в качестве значения. Вот простой пример использования того и другого подхода:

```
package stackoverflow;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Ru_so_168827_ListAndMap {

    // Класс для хранения имени и данных
    // (в этом примере данные -- просто число)
    static class Data {
        private String name;    // имя
        private int num;        // "данные" 
        Data(String name, int num) { // Конструктор создает объект с именем и данными
            this.name = name; this.num = num;}
        public String getName() { return name; }
        public int getNum() { return num; }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);
        String str = null;

        // Вводим словарь (или как по-русски будет map?) 
        Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>(); 
        System.out.print("Введите объекты для Map (\"end\" - конец ввода)\nИмя: ");
        while (!"end".equalsIgnoreCase(str = inp.nextLine())) {
            System.out.print("число: ");
            if (inp.hasNextInt()) {
                map.put(str, inp.nextInt()); // Добавляем ключ и число в словарь
                inp.nextLine();
                System.out.print("Имя: ");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Это не число. Закончим на этом");
                inp.nextLine();
                break;
            }
        }

        // Вводим список 
        List<Data> list = new ArrayList<>();
        System.out.print("\nВведите объекты для списка (\"end\" - конец ввода)\nИмя: ");
        while (!"end".equalsIgnoreCase(str = inp.nextLine())) {
            System.out.print("число: ");
            if (inp.hasNextInt()) {
            // Создаем объект и добавляем его в список:
                list.add(new Data(str, inp.nextInt())); 
                inp.nextLine();
                System.out.print("Имя: ");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Это не число. Закончим на этом");
                inp.nextLine();
                break;
            }
        }

        // Выводим словарь
        System.out.println("\nСодержимое словаря:");
        map.forEach((s, n) -> { 
            // Здесь в s получаем ключ, а в n -- значение
            System.out.printf("Имя: %s, значение: %s\n", s, n);});

        // Выводим список
        System.out.println("\nСодержимое списка:");
        list.forEach((d) -> { 
            // Здесь в d получаем объект с именем и данными
            System.out.printf("Имя: %s, значение: %s\n", d.getName(), d.getNum());});
    }

}
```